# Why am I getting and IOExeption when saving/loading to a dat file?

Tags: java, javafx, ioexception, fileinputstream

I am creating a program which takes the users input of name, id number, date, email and course choice and then saving it to file. Here is my code:

```
private class LoadMenuHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        try (ObjectInputStream loadData = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("ModuleChoices.dat"));) {
            profile = (StudentProfile) loadData.readObject();
            System.out.println("loaded");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfExcept) {
            System.out.println("not found");
        } catch (IOException ioExcept) {
            System.out.println("Error loading");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Class not found");
        }
        createProfile.setLoadProfile(profile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `StudentProfile` class implement Serializeable?
Can you post your stacktrace?

Comment: When catching the exception, print it also so you can see what is actually wrong, and post it here

Comment: My guess is `ModuleChoices.dat` file not found. Check your path.